# Nesting "Select Where" query

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I'm having trouble with creating a query for the following. In MySQL I created a View to combine a number of tables which gives me the following result:

ProductBrand     ProductName     Color
Brand-A          Product-A       Red
Brand-A          Product-B       Blue
Brand-B          Product-C       Red
Brand-B          Product-D       Green
Brand-B          Product-D       Brown

Now I want people to be able to search on a keyword and on MULTIPLE colors. The keyword should be either in ProductBrand or in ProductName. For that I wrote this SELECT statement:

SELECT FROM View_Products WHERE ProductBrand like '%$var%' or ProductName like '%$var%'

But I need to extend this with the color. The user can check multiple colors in the form. So I would normally do  SELECT FROM View_Products WHERE Color like '$color1' or Color like '$color2'.

How can I glue this together in a way that if a color is select in the form, it should be mandatory. In normal language: Show me all records where either ProductBrand or ProductName is equal to the searchterm and the color is either color1 or color2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Show me all records where either ProductBrand or ProductName is equal
>   to the searchterm and the color is either color1 or color2.

```
SELECT * FROM View_Products
WHERE (Productbrand LIKE '%$var%' OR ProductName LIKE '%$var%') AND
      (color LIKE '$color1' OR color LIKE '$color2')
```

Comment: Thanks, had done this but seemed I made an error in the ORDER BY part after the SELECT. Stupid me. This works now, thanks for your answer.